# Not getting the syntax of EXCEPT Right

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am sybase adaptive server `12.5.4` and this query does not seem to run

```
SELECT login,account from tempdb.guest.acct_info_dr3
EXCEPT
SELECT login,account from tempdb.guest.acct_info_dr2
```

I have checked white spaces etc. But I keep getting this error `Incorrect syntax near Except`.

Strangey MINUS which is oracle function worked.

Comment: The syntax is ok. Are you sure both tables exist ?

Comment: Yes the select statement works on both tables, so does union for both queries

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always rephrase this as a `left outer join`:

```
select dr3.login, dr3.account
from tempdb.guest.acct_info_dr3 left outer join
     (select distinct login, account
      from tempdb.guest.acct_info_dr2
     ) dr2
     on dr2.login = dr3.login and dr2.account = dr3.account
 where dr2.login is NULL
```

This will work, unless the columns contain NULL values.  If so, that can be fixed with additional logic.